Prevent single word to cause line break in bibliography
Is there any way to prevent single words like page numbers (e.g. pp. 20-22) to cause line break in bibliography?

I'm using natbib with following options:
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

These awkward line breaks are causing me precious space and even sparse pages, plz help.

you would have to change the bibliography style, which may not be an option if you are using a style mandated for an IEEE journal submission
